# Pivot table selection LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-blade

I have this problem I need to have the intitule of a mode via the ids in pivot table but it returns to me this :

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Here is my controller

```
$filiere = Filiere::all();
$fcount =  count($filiere);
$filiere22 = DB::select('select id from filiere');
foreach ($filiere22 as $filiere2 ){
    $md = DB::select('select intitule from mode_formation where id in(SELECT mode_id from mode_filiere where filiere_id='.$filiere2.')');
} return view('pgsec',compact('md','ssec','s_secteur','filiere','secteur','sec','secteur2','niveau','niv','province','pr','fcount','region','r','op','operateur'));
```

and here is my blade

```
@foreach($filiere as $f)
    <tr class="item{{$f->id}}">
        <td style="font-size: 13px;">
            <a href="f/{{$f->id}}">{{$f->intitule}}</a> 
        </td>
        @foreach($md as $m)
            <td style="font-size: 13px;">{{$m->intitule}}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What are the models that map `filiere`, `mode_formation` and `mode_filiere tables`? Also, the foreign keys and references from each one of those tables would be useful. Can you post them?

Comment: You can do this in a very simpler way just by using Eloquent relationships. I guess this is why @IGP asked about the models.

Comment: yes of cours thank you , filiere table has id , intitule , mode_formation has , id and intitule and mode_filiere table has : filiere_id , mode_id

Answer (score 0):

So according to the comments, your tables look like this:

```
+--------+  +--------------+  +------------------------------+
|filiere |  |mode_formation|  |mode_filiere                  |
+--------+  +--------------+  +------------------------------+
|id (pk) |  |id (pk)       |  |filiere_id (fk to filiere)    |
|intitule|  |intitule      |  |mode_id (fk to mode_formation)|
+--------+  +--------------+  +------------------------------+
```

Based on this and your code, I'm assuming the following:

- `Filiere` model uses `filiere` table.
- There is no model for the `mode_formation` table.
- There is no model for the `mode_filiere` table.

#### Step 1: Make a model for `mode_formation` table.

1. Run the command `php artisan make:model ModeFormation`
2. Just to make sure, edit the model file (located by default at `app/ModeFormation.php`) to add the table it represents.

#### Step 2: Add a `belongsToMany` relationship between `Filiere` and `ModeFormation` models

#### Step 3: Use `eager loading` in your controller to avoid running so many queries

#### Step 4: Use the relationship in your view

At the end, your models should look like this:

```php
# app/Filiere.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Filiere extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'filiere';

    public function mode_formations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ModeFormation::class, 'mode_filiere', 'filiere_id', 'mode_id');
    }
}
```

```php
# app/ModeFormation.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModeFormation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mode_formation';

    public function filieres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Filiere::class, 'mode_filiere', 'mode_id', 'filiere_id');
    }
}
```

That part in your controller should look like this:

```php
// you only need this one variable for what you're trying to accomplish
$filieres = Filiere::with('mode_formations')->get();
```

And your view:

```xml
@foreach($filieres as $filiere)
    <tr class="item{{ $filiere->id }}">
        <td style="font-size: 13px;">
            <a href="f/{{ $filiere->id }}">{{ $filiere->intitule }}</a> 
        </td>
        @foreach($filiere->mode_formations as $mode_formation)
            <td style="font-size: 13px;">{{ $mode_formation->intitule }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```